# how to open a cmd shell in windows and issue commands to that shell using python

Tags: python

I've tried

```
import os
os.system('cmd.exe')
```

great it opens up a cmd shell

but how do I write commands from my python script so that the opened shell executes it?

basically it's like this

open up a cmd shell and somehow get a hold of the instance of the opened shell and issue commands to it. the subprocess module doesn't seem to open a cmd shell im not trying to view the contents of the shell via the interpreter but actually
but that's what subprocess does?

so how can we open up a cmd shell and pass commands to that opened shell?

Comment: Take a look at python subprocess lib. Google it.

Comment: Do you need to keep it open? Is this an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What do you really need to achieve?

Comment: @PeterWood yeah I need the shell open it's just to activate my virtualenv 
using a script

Comment: @pregmatch I need the actual cmd shell and not just a subprocess to see the to the interpreter. can subprocess do that? open a cmd shell and pass the arguments to the opened shell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print process.returncode
```

The command variable should be for example: `cmd /k`. You can also add a `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` to the Popen argument list and write commands to cmd: 
`subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` the final code:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen('cmd /k ', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=None)
process.stdin.write("dir") #passing command
stdOutput,stdError = process.communicate()
print stdOutput
process.stdin.close()
```

Or alternatively:

```
from subprocess import *
Popen("cmd /k dir")
```

Comment: there is an error on line 3.

 `process.stdin.write("dir")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 4):

to anyone having the same problems as me

I needed to get a handle on the command prompt window and and wanted to activate my virtualenv and run my `.py` file programatically.

I used **pywin32com** and after hours of researching stackoverflow and the web

I managed to get a working solution

I don't know much about the subprocess module but and I don't know if it let's you send different commands  to the opened **command prompt**

but here is my working solution

```
import time
import os
from win32com import client
from  win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow, SetForegroundWindow, EnumWindows
from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId


class ActivateVenv:

    def set_cmd_to_foreground(self, hwnd, extra):
        """sets first command prompt to forgeround"""

        if "cmd.exe" in GetWindowText(hwnd):
            SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
            return

    def get_pid(self):
        """gets process id of command prompt on foreground"""

        window = GetForegroundWindow()
        return GetWindowThreadProcessId(window)[1]

    def activate_venv(self, shell, venv_location):
        """activates venv of the active command prompt"""

        shell.AppActivate(self.get_pid())
        shell.SendKeys("cd \ {ENTER}")
        shell.SendKeys(r"cd %s {ENTER}" % venv_location)
        shell.SendKeys("activate {ENTER}")

    def run_py_script(self,shell):
        """runs the py script"""

        shell.SendKeys("cd ../..{ENTER}")
        shell.SendKeys("python run.py {ENTER}")

    def open_cmd(self, shell):
        """ opens cmd """

        shell.run("cmd.exe")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    shell = client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    run_venv = ActivateVenv()
    run_venv.open_cmd(shell)
    EnumWindows(run_venv.set_cmd_to_foreground, None)
    run_venv.activate_venv(shell, "flask3.5/venv/scripts")
    run_venv.run_py_script(shell)
```

Comment: Great solution!