# Is it possible to open a terminal from an ongoing subprocess in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, subprocess, tmux, gnu-screen

I am using the subprocess module in Python to navigate and run commands on behalf of a user.
I now want to be able to open the terminal session so that the user can enter their own commands.

I have used Tmux and Screen to create a shared terminal session and I have had no luck.

When initiating the shared terminal session with **Tmux** through the subprocess module I get the error:

`"Open terminal failed: not a terminal"`

and with **Screen**, I get the error:

`"Must be connected to a terminal"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try win32proccess and give direct commands to shell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059905/how-to-open-a-cmd-shell-in-windows-and-issue-commands-to-that-shell-using-python

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΓρηγορόπουλος I forgot to add that I am using Linux.