# How to get the output (string) from an open cmd.exe window?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

I am in the same situation as the person who asked this question and at the same time he managed to answer it using "win32(something)" instead of "subprocess": [how to open a cmd shell in windows and issue commands to that shell using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059905/how-to-open-a-cmd-shell-in-windows-and-issue-commands-to-that-shell-using-python)

I am partially satisfied with this answer, but I have encountered a new problem: How do I "capture" the outputs (strings) generated by each command line (or at least the last command line used)?

To give you a more contextual idea, I use a program that requires command lines in cmd.exe (imagemagick), I use it to compare images and, using a complex statistical criterion, I obtain a floating number between 0 and 1.

Precisely that number is the one I want to capture.

[Explicit example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ6EH.gif)

This is my current code:

```
import time
```

import os
from win32com import client
from  win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow, SetForegroundWindow, EnumWindows
from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId

class ActivateVenv:

```
def set_cmd_to_foreground(self, hwnd, extra):
    """sets first command prompt to forgeround"""

    if "cmd.exe" in GetWindowText(hwnd):
        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
        return

def get_pid(self):
    """gets process id of command prompt on foreground"""

    window = GetForegroundWindow()
    return GetWindowThreadProcessId(window)[1]

def activate_venv(self, shell, venv_location):
    """activates venv of the active command prompt"""

    shell.AppActivate(self.get_pid())
    #shell.SendKeys("cd \ {ENTER}")
    #shell.SendKeys(r"cd %s {ENTER}" % venv_location)
    #shell.SendKeys("activate {ENTER}")

def run_py_script(self,shell):
    """runs the py script"""

    shell.SendKeys("cd ../..{ENTER}")
    shell.SendKeys("python run.py {ENTER}")
    
def run_script(self,shell,command_line):
    """runs a general script"""

    shell.SendKeys(command_line)

def open_cmd(self, shell):
    """ opens cmd """

    shell.run("cmd.exe")
    time.sleep(1)
    
def comparar(p,q):
try:
    return 'magick compare -metric ncc C:\GTSgiffer\INput\{}.png C:\GTSgiffer\INput\{}.png null: 2>&1'.format(p,q)
except:
    print(f"Error en comparar({p},{q})")
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

'''shell = client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
run_venv = ActivateVenv()
run_venv.open_cmd(shell)
EnumWindows(run_venv.set_cmd_to_foreground, None)
run_venv.activate_venv(shell, "flask3.5/venv/scripts")
run_venv.run_py_script(shell)'''

shell = client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
run_venv = ActivateVenv()
run_venv.open_cmd(shell)
EnumWindows(run_venv.set_cmd_to_foreground, None)
run_venv.activate_venv(shell, "flask3.5/venv/scripts")
run_venv.run_script(shell,r"cd C:\GTSgiffer\bin {ENTER}")
run_venv.run_script(shell,comparar(1,2)+" {ENTER}")
run_venv.run_script(shell,comparar(1,3)+" {ENTER}")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `subprocess`?

Comment: Hello @FARS, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please copy and paste your code/command and its desired output directly into the post instead of linking to an animated gif.

Comment: To Paul M.: I would likt to use "subprocess", but I don't how how to send a command line from a Python script to a open cmd.exe window without closing that window. I use win32(somthing) because that was the only solution that it workd to me.

Comment: To Yatin: It's a very long code from my script, but the main idea is the same from this old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059905/how-to-open-a-cmd-shell-in-windows-and-issue-commands-to-that-shell-using-python

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from subprocess import run
>>> result = run("magick compare -metric ncc 1.jpg 2.jpg null:", capture_output=True)
>>> result
CompletedProcess(args='magick compare -metric ncc 1.jpg 2.jpg null:', returncode=1, stdout=b'', stderr=b'0.25404')
>>> result.stderr
b'0.25404'
```

Try using the run function introduced in Python 3.5.
Its the recommended way to invoke a process.

[subprocess run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

You can also use the following, but its not required.

```
result = run("cmd.exe /c magick compare -metric ncc 1.jpg 2.jpg null:", capture_output=True)
```

Comment: Basically, what I want is, from an already open cmd.exe window, to send a command and then get its result, but without closing that same cmd.exe window. Repeatedly send several commands to the same cmd.exe window, because I want to get many numerical results to process several images.

Comment: The answer you gave me I already knew, but the bad thing is that it closes the cmd.exe window once the sent command line is over.

Comment: ok, I might have read it wrong, you said in your original post that you need to capture the number. Anyways, since you posted your code post my comment. I must have missed your code.

It makes more sense now.

Comment: @FARS just use `result = run("cmd.exe /k magick compare -metric ncc 1.jpg 2.jpg null:", capture_output=True)` instead to keep it open?

Comment: To Neko Musume: I want to keep open the cmd.exe because I want to send a command to delete file later: "del something.png". I tried before to work with ephemeral windows (which open, execute a command, and then close), but this gives me an error in the long run and fails to store the float numbers (the outputs I want to keep).